# My PoS validator node is syncing slow, how can I increase the sync speed?

Tags: polygon-pos

I have deployed a sentry and validator node on an AWS instance (sentry - m5d.4xlarge and validator - m5d.8xlarge).

My bor version is 0.4.0 and my heimdall version is 0.3.4

I realised the nodes are syncing really slow. What steps can I take to speed this up?

Answer (score 0):

**A Few suggestions from our end would be**

1.Check whether the node is meeting the normal sync speeds i.e. Node sync rate should be at 15-20 blocks every 8 secs.

2.Maintain the recommended IOPS for the Disk. We recommend 16000 IOPS for the nodes.

3.Ensure you are meeting our system specifications

https://wiki.polygon.technology/docs/pos/operate/validator/validator-node-system-requirements/

4.Ensure you are using SSD disk not the HDD disks.

**Despite of following all the suggestions if incase you are still facing issues**

1.Set the cache value on the config.toml to 40% of your total RAM.

2.If the issue still persists then try adding some additional peers.

3.And finally in spite of following all the suggestions if you are facing issue upgrade your disk type io1 disks on AWS Instances.